# ArangoDB Post-filtering aggregated data

Tags: filter, arangodb

I'm stuck with filtering on aggregated data using ArangoDB

Imagine a graph with user documents. Every user has a number of game consoles. So the graph is

User -[]-> GameConsole

I need a query that lists all users with its game consoles. AND I want to be able to FILTER for all users with a specific game console but the query result still needs to show ALL consoles of the user (if he has more than one)

I took the example for post-filtering aggregated data from the Arango DB docs: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-grouping.html an modified it to my needs:

```
FOR u IN User
   FOR c IN 1..1 OUTBOUND u plays
   COLLECT userData = u INTO consoles = c
   FILTER "GameConsole/Playstation3" IN consoles
RETURN {userData, consoles}
```

Expected result

```
[
 { "userData": 
   {
     "_id": "User/JohnDoe",
     "Name": "John Doe"
   },
   "consoles": [
     {
       "_id": "GameConsole/Playstation3",
       "Name: "Playstation 3"
     },
     {
       "_id": "GameConsole/Wii",
       "Name": "Wii"
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

But the result is an empty array:

```
[
  []
]
```

Same for

```
[...]
FILTER consoles == "GameConsole/Playstation3"
FILTER consoles._id == "GameConsole/Playstation3"
FILTER consoles[*]._id == "GameConsole/Playstation3"
```

What is the correct query/FILTER statement to show all users that own a Playstation3 AND list all consoles they own?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. As consoles is an array and I need to filter on attribute (like _id), I need to expand the array when filtering: consoles[*]._id

So the working query is

```
FOR u IN User
   FOR c IN 1..1 OUTBOUND u plays
   COLLECT userData = u INTO consoles = c
   FILTER "GameConsole/Playstation3" IN consoles[*]._id
RETURN {userData, consoles}
```

Hope that helps anyone else.